# Including a Python Flask .conf file in nginx.conf with Windows

Tags: python, windows, nginx, flask, reverse-proxy

I'm creating Flask API's on Windows. I'm using `waitress` as WSGI and it's hosted at a Windows server machine. I want to reverse proxy in order to have multiple ports with the same service (since the service take a bit of time like 6 seconds). I'm already using multi-threading but I really need to reverse proxy that. I created a `python.conf` file:

```
upstream flask_api {

    server localhost:8000;
    server localhost:5000;
    server localhost:5001;
}

server {
        listen 80;

        location /service {
            proxy_pass "http://flask_api/service";
        }
}
```

where I'm simply trying to be able to access multiple ports when `localhost/service` is requested, the localhosts are already running. I've read some tutorials but still get error 404 when I try `localhost/service` (same error if I type anything after `/` that I didn't specify). Because of that I think the `python.conf` file is not being included at the `nginx.conf` file. How can I do that on Windows? I wrote :

```
    include servers/*;
    include C:\Users\Gabriel\loadbalancer\python.conf;
```

at the end of `http{ }` in `nginx.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of worked when I erased the entire nginx.config file and rewrote it directly, that's how it looks now:

```
events { }

http {
        upstream flask_api {

        server localhost:8000;
        server localhost:5000;
        server localhost:5001;
    }

    server {
            listen 80;
            location /service {
                proxy_pass "http://flask_api/service";
            }
    }
}
```

The ports are just returning "serving on port  'x'" so when I make a browser request it shows me the message. But when I refresh it the request never end, but once I stop this frozen request and make another one it works perfectly.

Comment: Its a windows nginx upstream delay (60 seconds). To fix it just add this line:

proxy_connect_timeout 1s;